# In Outlook, composing a message, can I visually tag it somehow in VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a some VBA that will file an outgoing message as a Task (and do some other things) if I tag it.  One way I tag is by calling a macro that sets a UserProperty; I have assigned the macro to a button on the command bar.

I would like to visually mark the message as having been tagged before I send it, and then implement a toggle, but I'm struggling to find a way of doing it.  So keeping the button depressed, or highlighted, would work but I can't see how to do this in the Fluent UI stuff.  Alternatively, I'd like to add something to the area to the right of the "pop out" "discard" buttons at the top of the message.

I tried adding a category to the new message, but this is not displayed in the pane.  I do have a UserProperty assigned, but I don't know how to display that either.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

VBA doesn't allow customizing the Fluent UI. You need to develop a COM add-in instead. To implement a toggle button on the Ribbon you need to define callbacks where you may check the user property value and update the UI accordingly. The Fluent UI is described in-depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)